# Python TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects

Tags: python, mysql

I have few User provided information like `username`, `password`, `email`, etc. that user provides in a config file.

I have the parsed data from the config file using configParser module.

I want to enter these information to MySQL database.

The Data is like:

```
Usename="ABC"
password="ABC@1"
email="abc123@xyz.com"
```

My insert statement is like:

```
"INSERT INTO userinfo (group_ID, rank_ID, login, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('" + groupid + "', '" + rankID + "', '" + userid + "', '" + password + "', '" + fname + "', '" + lname + "', '" + email + "')"
```

But it is not executing, as I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects
```

I have tried doing: `str(password)`, `str(email)` for the variables with mixed types, but no luck.

Here, `group_ID` and `rank_ID` are integers.

I have tried the following as suggested by one of the experts:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo (group_ID, rank_ID, login, password, first_name, last_name, email) "
"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
(groupid, rankID, userid, password, fname, lname, email)
try:
  c.execute(sql4)
  conn.commit()
except StandardError, e:
  print e
  conn.rollback()
```

But the error I get is: `query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple`

What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't interpolate values into your query yourself. Leave that to the database adapter, by using SQL parameters:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO userinfo (group_ID, rank_ID, login, password, first_name, last_name, email) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    (groupid, rankID, userid, password, fname, lname, email))
```

The standard Python-MySQL adapter uses `%s` as parameter placeholders, other database adapters may use `?` instead.

This has the added advantage that MySQL will figure out for you how to quote each value, prevent SQL injection attacks, and gives the database the chance to cache the query plan for the query and just slot in future values.

Comment: It doesn't give me the error anymore, but data is not uploading.
It says: `query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple`

Comment: @aki2all: Then your first argument is not a string; make sure that it is. My code uses two strings, but since there is only whitespace in between Python combines those into one.

Comment: Here, my `group_ID` and `rank_ID` are integers. I have tried using `%d` as well as `str(group_ID)`
None of them seems to work. As data is not uploaded.

Comment: @aki2all: You need to use `%s`, always. MySQL will take care of integers for you. Did you commit your transaction with `connection.commit()`?

Comment: @aki2all: If you still get an exception, then no insertion will take place *at all*, of course.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters
Yes I have done `conn.commit()`, yet it doesn't upload.

Comment: And you are 100% certain your INSERT executed? If you have both an INSERT and a commit *on the same connection* then you should see the new row. What are you using to verify that the insertion took place?

Comment: I am executing the following code:

    `sql4 = """INSERT INTO userinfo (group_ID, rank_ID, login, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (groupid, rankID, userid, password, fname, lname, email)

  try:

    c.execute(sql4)

    conn.commit()

    print "User Added with userID: %s\n" % userid 

  except StandardError, e:

    print e

    conn.rollback()`

Its getting the error:

`query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple`

Comment: @aki2all: You are creating a tuple, then passing it to the function. That doesn't work, because that's **one** tuple argument. Assign **just** the string to `sql4`, then call `c.execute(sql4, (groupid, rankID, userid, password, fname, lname, email))`.